# Automatically size a div's width according to a table within it

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I have a table that is automatically generated using a program. The program designates each column to have a specific `max-width`. I want the containing div to only be as wide as it needs to be to fit the table. There are other elements on the page that might go beyond the width of the table, as well. So I'm wondering if there is a way to go about this properly.

You can see exactly what I'm talking about here:
http://jsfiddle.net/ck9TB/1/

It seems fine without the "disclaimer" div, so I'm thinking maybe I need to adjust that?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this.

First, change the id to a class, `.logTable` instead of `#logTable`, this takes care of your rule for `max-width`.

Apply `display: inline-block` to `.logTable`, which will cause the `div` to take on a shrink-to-fit width.

```
.logTable {
    border: 1px dashed blue;
    display: inline-block;
}
.logTable th, .logtable td {
    max-width:105px;
}
```

The dashed blue border shows the edges of `.logTable`.

The light blue background comes from the background-color of the `body` and not related to `.logTable`.

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/96yeW/

Comment: Ah, good catch. Forgot to switch that to a class. But I'm still having the issue, even after the switch

http://jsfiddle.net/ck9TB/4/

Comment: @SalmonMode Can you describe the issue more precisely? Which containing div are you referring to? I assumed it was `.logTable`, you must be thinking of something else.  And what makes you think there is and issue?

Comment: If you go to the jsfiddle, you can see. The table has it's own width, because I have set the max width for each column individually. But if there is other content on the page that goes beyond that width, the table does not prevent them from expanding. I do not want any other elements on the page(besides the page itself of course) to be wider than the table, but the disclaimer div is too wide, and causes the other elements to expand. If you remove the disclaimer div, you will see my desired layout(nothing wider than the table)